# trouble trying to pass an array via stringify to php

Tags: php, ajax

I can't figure out why this doesn't work, please help!!  I just get the message "decoded ="

```
mydata = JSON.stringify(array_str_idnum);

$.ajax({
type:           'post',
cache:          false,
url:            'parser.php',
data:           mydata,
datatype:       'json',
success: function(msg){
         $("#formstatus").ajaxComplete(function(){$(this).html(msg)});
           }        
});
```

---

```
<?php

// decode JSON string to PHP object
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['myJson'],true);

echo "decoded =";
echo $decoded;

?>
```

Comment: Have you dumped the contents of $_POST to see what's contained in it ?

Comment: Try to print the last errror (if any) with `json_last_error`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but doesn't data have to contain a query string? You could try using "data: 'myJson=' + mydata" instead of just "data: mydata". Either way, I don't see any myJson data being set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@Reanimation` suggests, you need to send the parameter that will hold the JSON data. I would recommend doing it more JavaScriptish way as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    url: 'parser.php',
    data: {'myJson': mydata},
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
            $("#formstatus").ajaxComplete(function(){$(this).html(msg)});
    }        
});
```

The other thing is that `$decoded` will actually hold an array as long as the original `array_str_idnum` is array, so doing `echo $decoded` will output `Array()`. Note also that the second paramerter to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is to return the objects as associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I implemented this and did a var dumpstring(33) "[[\"1316333978281\"],[\"moved\"]]"

Comment: Thanks everyone, I implemented this and did a var dump on the $_POST variable which returned: "string(33) "[[\"1316333978281\"],[\"moved\"]]""  It's the right data in the brackets, but it doesn't seem to want to decode it into an array. I'll keep trying!

Comment: as it turns out, I didn't need to stringify the array first, it gets passed on alright as it is.  Thanks again to those who helped me.